# Using Javascript to generate HTML that contains JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, view

I am making a web view using jsp, javascript and html. I have a list of elements that when clicked on calls among other things the javascript function generatePictureSlider. The idea is that a set of pictures is associated with each element in the list and a slider is created when one of the elements is clicked on.

This is the code that creates my list:

```
<div class="valg">
    <ol id="selectable">
    <c:forEach items="${kandidatliste}" var="kjoretoy" varStatus="rowCounter">

        <li id="${rowCounter.index}" class="ui-widget-content">
            <c:choose>
               /*Some code that displays content based on a variable in the kjoretoy var */
            </c:choose>

            <c:out value="Reg nr: ${kjoretoy.kjennemerke} "/>
            <c:out value="Score: ${kjoretoy.score} "/>
            <c:out value="Passering: ${kjoretoy.passeringsString} "/>                       

            <input id="removeVehicle" type="submit" value="X" />
            <input id="checkVehicle" type="submit" value="Sjekk"/>
        </li>   
    </c:forEach>        
    </ol>
</div>
```

The #selectable ol is bound to a click function in javascript. This click function is the one that calls on generatePictureSlider. So, when one of the elements in the list is clicked on, I want to display the pictures associated with the element in a slider.

Thus, I have to generate the html that displays the slider dynamically.

My problem is that I get this error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+parseInt(index)+"`

Index here is naturally the index of the element that has been click, which corresponds to the place the element has in an arraylist which the view has received from the Java application. This arraylist is called "kandidatliste" as you will see in the function under.

```
function generatePictureSlider(index){
    $('div#switcher-panel').html('');

    var html = '<div id="container">'+
        '<div id="banner">'+
        '<ul class="bjqs">'+
        '<li><img src="/nonstop/bildekjennemerke=${kandidatliste['+parseInt(index)+'].kjennemerke}&bildeNr=${0}" title="${kandidatliste[0].kjennemerke}_${0}" width="350" height="220"/></li>'+
        '</ul></div></div>';

    $('div#switcher-panel').append(html);               
}
```

How can I make the javascript variable index be an integer so that the JSP does not crash and shows the picture associated with the element in index index.

I am of course open to other suggestions on how to solve it. The essence is that based on the element a user clicks on, I want to show images and other data associated with that element on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP pages runs server-side, and prints an HTML document that may include Javascript, on the other hand, Javascript runs in the client's browser, it doesn't make sense to generate JSP with javascript because it'll be on the client's browser, and it won't work since JSP must be resolved server-side, you need to resolve this before send it to the client, you could use a Scriptlet, but i don't recommend it, i don't know exactly how your app works, but i would load the pictures dinamically using ajax.

If you provide more information i could improve the answer.

Comment: I am not that familiar with jsp. I have used javascript to generate html with this method before, but never html that has jsp "code".

I tried to explain the functionality I was after in my original post. I can try to update my OP with some more of the code in the jsp

Comment: have you tried to use just index, instead of parseInt(index)?

Comment: When you do:
<img src="/nonstop/bildekjennemerke=${kandidatliste['+parseInt(index)+'].kjennemerke}&bildeNr=${0}" title="${kandidatliste[0].kjennemerke}_${0}" width="350" height="220"/>

When you say ${value}, and you are appending this inside the html document, i understand that this is being interpreted by the client's browser, i understand that ${value} must be a local reference from the client's context, im not familiar with that notation in html, what should it do? and how is that parameter retrieved?

Comment: I ended up rewriting my JSP to call the server when a user clicked on a list element to get the element's data from the server which is then displayed to the user. To me, this seems a bit unneccessary as the data is already there, but it works, so I am happy. 

I also restructured a bit so that the list of elements and the display panel where the data of a clicked element is displayed are in two separate files. This way, I don't need to reload the entire page when a list element is clicked on. Neither is the data in the display panel reset when the list is updated.